# Av HaRachamim after Yizkor

Tags: tefilla, yizkor

Is the Av HaRachamim that is said after Yizkor part of the [Yizkor service](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/yizkor.html) and only said by those who said Yizkor or is it part of the regular Tefila to be said by all? (sources)

Comment: What's a "Yizkor service"?

Comment: I still have no idea what a "Yizkor service" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chabad on line](http://www.col.org.il/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%91%D7%93_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99_%D7%97%D7%91%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_77987.html) says that the entire Congregation, even those that do not say Yizkor, say Av Harachamim.

Comment: That source is a bit ambiguous. All it really says is that someone within the first year who is staying in shul anyway, says the Av Harachamim even though they didn't say Yizkor.